# Как создать маску для проверки строки в JS?

Tags: javascript

Помогите создать маску для проверки строки в JS. То есть должна быть проверка строковой переменной по следующей маске. `#article[1-10000]`. В начале обязательна строка: `#article`, а после проверка на наличие любого числа, допустим, от 1 до 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно регулярное выражение:

```
^\#article\[([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|1000)\]$
```

Использовать с помощью вызова

```
regexp.test(string);
```